# Htaccess Disallow access to folders and subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wish to redirect www.domain.com/folder1 and all other subdirectories(eg: www.domain.com/folder1/filename.php) to index page. Meaning users should not have access to folder1 and its subdirectories, instead should be redirected to index page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ /index.php [R=301]
RewriteRule ^folder1$ /index.php [R=301]
```

Comment: Didnt work. I am still able to access www.domain.com/folder1/

Comment: In which folder is your .htaccess file ? In the root ?

Comment: Yes. It is in the root folder.

Comment: Gave Internal Server Error!! Found an alternative solution. Deleted the folder and redirected 404 error to index page then. Anyways, Thanks.